# Manage non-renewable / renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, subscriptions, auto-renewable

I am currently developing an iOS app which contains non-renewable and renewable subscriptions. In my understanding, the "Subscriptions menu" in iOS (as described here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039) only lists renewable subscriptions within the same subscription group and not non-renewable subscriptions.

Is this assumption correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my assumption was correct.